Can someone help me set up junit correctly? My program is not compiling
My code:
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class AListTest {
    @Test
    public void testEmptySize() {
        AList L = new AList();
        assertEquals(0, L.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddAndSize() {
        AList L = new AList();
        L.addLast(99);
        L.addLast(99);
        assertEquals(2, L.size());
    }
    ...rest of testing
}

I have both junit 4.13.2 and also 5.9.1 jupiter included in my dependencies because I was confused about what package to put in my project stucture/dependencies.
I am following this class by the way and I am trying to follow the commands at this part of this video...
The commands I am trying to run are
javac *.java

-and also-

time java speedtestAList 

I have tried compiling with every permutation of those packages and none in my dependencies. I keep getting the same errors no matter what:
AListTest.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
AListTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                       ^
SpeedTestSLList.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
AListTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class AListTest
AListTest.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class AListTest
AListTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
....on like that through my file

I don't know why testing is always so hard for me. I use C# normally and Xunit and moq give me so so much trouble too. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?
I have tried including different dependencies and using ai to troubleshoot. I have asked a couple friends who have been unable to help so far. I googled of course. I tried to rebuild the project every time I changed dependencies. I tried to "invalidated the caches" in intellij.

You haven't shown/explained exactly how you've added the dependencies. I'd really suggest using Maven or Gradle to manage your project, as described below (and see the links in the answer for their documentation).

I solved this now by running
javac -classpath <path_to_junit.jar>:/your_system_libraries *.java
and I had to actually be in WSL to run the test command I was trying.
I am still really confused by what maven and gradle are. Are they companies? Is it a framework like react or something?

Did you read any of their documentation? In short, they are tools that manage project structure, building (e.g. compiling and running tests) and packaging (e.g. producing a JAR) and third party dependencies

You need to add the .jar file for JUnit to your build and execution process.
javac -classpath <path_to_junit.jar>:/your_system_libraries *.java

then (assuming you have a void main(String args[]) defined somewhere that executes the junit tests, otherwise you need to call a different execution engine)
java -classpath .:<path_to_junit.jar>:/your_system_libraries AListTest

In practice, nobody really executes on the command line like this.  Virtually everyone uses a maven or gradle configuration to manage the build and execution process, so that you don't have to worry about managing downloads, and classpaths, and versions and stuff.
Once you install maven, you can add a configuration that looks like this to identify that you want to use junit:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

which instructs maven to add this to the build (during the test phase, in this case, as noted by the scope.
Then, build and execution is much simpler:
mvn package
mvn test

I recommend one of the following tools:

Maven
Gradle

There are others, but these two are most commonly used in my experience.

Being honest, I don't understand a lot of what you wrote. I have been confused by testing for a while but I don't want to give up... I just don't understand all these interdependencies.
What is a jar file? Do I write that myself? I also don't know what a classpath is.
Can you explain what an execution engine is?
What is maven and gradle? and what is a configuration?
Where do I add the code that you listed? How do I install maven? Is this through intellij or is this in java or something?

Try the tutorial links I put at the bottom.  That can get you going on a working setup.  The maven one is a bit easier to understand.

Jar files are Java's version of packaged delivered code, like assemblies in C# or .so files in Linux C/C++.  In the java world, you will be delivering packaged jars (or similar depending on your requirements).  The classpath is the basic construct that tells java where to find jars and classes it uses during runtime.  The execution engine is like a makefile, maven, gradle, cmake or any other build engine out there.  I really think you ought to try a tutorial step by step and not try to skip to the end.

The documentation still seems very cryptic to me after reading their website. I might just be missing knowledge or something.
"Maven, a Yiddish word meaning accumulator of knowledge, began as an attempt to simplify the build processes in the Jakarta Turbine project. . JARs were checked into CVS. We wanted a standard way to build the projects, a clear definition of what the project consisted of, an easy way to publish project information, and a way to share JARs across several projects.
The result is a tool that can now be used for building and managing any Java-based project..."

I don't know what this is- The Jakarta project? What does 'building' mean? I have compiled programs but I don't know what building a program means. Is CVS the same thing as source control? Isn't publishing just pushing to github?

There are a lot of steps to becoming a new programmer.  I recommend reading tutorials, not just the first paragraph of the home page.  Start here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

I am trying to learn one thing at a time; and I want to learn how to use junit and test and the person teaching the class didn't mention maven/gradle at all and before I spend time investing energy into learning how to use these things, I like to understand what they are used for.\I read through the other pages as well but it is all relatively equally cryptic and it all sounds like things that intellij does and what the IDE is for.
Your first solution did work for me in the end though!!! So I am very grateful for your help and I will still try and learn what maven and gradle are eventually.

Ah, yes.  Well, the IDE is helpful for you as a developer, but in a team you need a repeatable process, which is what maven is for.  I wish you good luck in your studies!


I have both junit 4.13.2 and also 5.9.1 jupiter

Don’t. Do not mix old and new JUnit.
JUnit 5 is a giant rewrite, with a new architecture that recognizes that JUnit versions 1-4 had evolved to being used not only for writing & running its own tests but also for running tests written in other test frameworks. So JUnit 5 was rebuilt to explicitly provide a harness not only for its own tests but for other tests as well.
For JUnit 5, the framework was broken apart into separate pieces of functionality. The oversight of executing tests, while managing and reporting results, in contained in the “engine“, JUnit Platform. Writing tests was split out to become JUnit Jupiter. Running old JUnit 3 & 4 tests was split out to be JUnit Vintage. So now JUnit Jupiter and JUnit Vintage are two of several testing frameworks that “plug into” JUnit Platform.
See this diagram taken from a tutorial by IBM.

New tests
JUnit Jupiter is the sub-framework within JUnit that can be used to write and run tests. Such tests can be run by the main JUnit 5 framework that harnesses tests from any of several test frameworks. To use Jupiter for writing your tests, use the JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator) Maven dependency to bring both the JUnit 5 main framework, the “engine”, as well as the Jupiter sub-framework.
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Old tests
A parallel sub-framework, JUnit Vintage, was written in JUnit 5 to execute legacy tests written in JUnit 3 & 4. If you are working on a project that already has such tests, add this sub-framework to your project. If you are working on a Greenfield project that has no old tests, then do not add this sub-framework — just write your new tests in Jupiter.
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


I can't use comments yet, but I have been at the OP's point of frustration as well.
You are trying to use/write Java on the command line, just as I used to do with C or C++.  Java's "ecosystem" doesn't do well using that method.  I have tried and sort of succeeded, but an IDE works better.  For the record, you can get Intellij for free on Windows or Linux.  If you are a student, you certainly can.  Check JetBrains web site.
Maven or Gradle is the best way to keep build/compile things straight in Java.  To that, the best way to use Maven or Gradle is to use Intellij or Eclipse.  These are the two best IDE's on the market.
Yes, they can hide a lot of things you would rather know.  But, as a begining Java programmer, they hide a lot of things you don't need to know right now.  That's from experience.
First real answer: Stop trying to understand Testing or JUnit testing right now.  That will come in time.  Glad you have encountered it in a class setting.
Testing is what we do when we are proving that our code works.  We write tests on our classes and their methods that "assert" certain outcomes and we see if our classes/methods produced that outcome.
JUnit is a popular testing framework.  IMO, it is best run inside an IDE (Intellij or Eclipse) with Maven or Gradle supervising.  However, the idea of writing tests doesn't even need JUnit.  You can write tests with regular Java code but written so that your methods prove they can handle all types of input, bad or good.
So, short answer: get an IDE, learn to use it, choose maven or gradle then stick to that as much as possible, as time progresses, learn to write unit tests.  Crawl, walk, run, marathon.  Do it in order and you'll grow faster.
